# Do a periodical commit in a large update query

Tags: sql, oracle10g, periodic-processing

I'm newbie with pl/sql and i need to do a large update in my database. More than 4 million entries must be changed and i want to execute a commit after every 5.000 update. I'm pretty lost to do this.

Here my query.

```
update accounts a set a.validateid = 'TH20381', flagexport = 25, exportname ='zde'
where a.accountnumber >= 35026879 and a.ownerid like 'V35%';
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Frequent commits only make the whole thing slower, not faster. Btw: in your example there is no PL/SQL whatsoever. PL/SQL is **only** used for stored procedures.

Comment: I don't want to overcharger the UNDO tablespace. And avoid the system get collapsed trying to do 4 million updates, if there is an error in the update number 2k, all the updates after that could be done or not.

Comment: In sql server we do this with a loop that processses x number of records at a time. Usually I use a staging table and then update the ones I've processed and tehn select the next 5000 from teh staging table where the update bit is null. Then loop through til you are done. Not sure if that is the best way in Oracle.

Comment: Please don't be fooled into thinking that not *overcharing the UNDO tablespace* is somehow a good solution. You should minimize the number of commits to the bare minimum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need to do that, you can consider using `DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE` package. Here is an example how it would look like:

```
DECLARE
  v_sql VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  -- create the task
  DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.create_task (task_name => 'update_accounts_task');

  -- define how the task should be split
  DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.create_chunks_by_rowid(task_name   => 'update_accounts_task',
                                               table_owner => 'YOUR_USERNAME',
                                               table_name  => 'ACCOUNTS',
                                               by_row      => true,
                                               chunk_size  => 5000);

  -- command to be split and executed - notice the condition on rowid
  -- which is required since we defined above that the task should be split
  -- by rowid
  v_sql   := 'UPDATE accounts
                 SET validateid = ''TH20381'',
                     flagexport = 25,
                     exportname = ''zde''
               WHERE accountnumber >= 35026879
                 AND ownerid LIKE ''V35%''
                 AND rowid BETWEEN :start_id AND :end_id';

  -- run the task
  DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.run_task(task_name      => 'update_accounts_task',
                                 sql_stmt       => v_sql,
                                 language_flag  => DBMS_SQL.NATIVE,
                                 parallel_level => 10);
END;
```

The user creating the task must be granted the `CREATE JOB` privilege.

Based on article by Tim Hall accessible here: [DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE at Oracle Base](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/dbms_parallel_execute_11gR2.php)

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger I didn't say it is more elegant, merely provided a possible solution to author's problem.